# Use media query inline style

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I know it sounds ridiculous, but can I use a css media query in an inline style? The reason is I'm echoing a background in PHP and need to use a retina size image if the device is retina.

`ie: <div style="background:url(normal.png); <- need to add style for retina device`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***Not within an inline style declaration as far as I know.***

However, if you're echoing from within PHP and **really** can't access the stylesheet I would suggest echoing an inline `<style />` element with the media query and using a class for the div.

**i.e.**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .bg {
        background: url(background.jpg);
    }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { /* Change to whatever media query you require */
        .bg {
             background: url(background_highres.jpg);
        }
    }

</style>
<div class="bg">...</div>
```

Comment: Does this break the convention of injecting style outside the head though?

Comment: You don't have to put it outside the page head.