# How do I make .py-md-6 override .p-3 in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I defined

```
.py-md-6 {
  padding-top: 6rem !important;
  padding-bottom: 6rem !important;  
}
```

And I have an element (HAML)

```
#id.p-3.py-md-6
```

However it shows that the `.p-3` class overrides the `.py-md-6` class.

I tried to put the `.py-md-6` before the `.p-3` but it didn't work. I tried to use `.p-sm-3` instead but it's defined with `@media (min-width: 576px)` and still overrides the `.py-md-6`.

I want small padding on mobile (because there's not a lot of screen space), and I want large padding on desktop.

---

I tried one of the answers which works in CodePly, but it's not working locally.

[image]

Comment: try writing inline style for the element using style property. I think inline styles get max priority .

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth That doesn't seem to work. `<div class="p-3" id="deal-flow" style="@media (min-width: 768px) { padding-top: 6rem !important; padding-bottom: 6rem !important; }">`. It doesn't show the element style in the inspector. It doesn't seem possible to use a media query for inline styles. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023157/use-media-query-inline-style#13023210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from @ZimSystem, I re-arranged the `link` tags in my app so that Bootstrap comes first and my `application.css` comes after. From

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' 
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
%link{:crossorigin => "anonymous", :href => "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css", :integrity => "sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
```

To

```
%link{:crossorigin => "anonymous", :href => "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css", :integrity => "sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

Then my app definitions will override the earlier Bootstrap definitions. And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check out @media screen. Bootstrap uses it. I think you could change all grid padding to 6 except for the mobile screen. Or a singel Class IF It suites your case better

I use sass to precompile the style, but this can be done the old fashion way aswell. In your own stylesheet:

```
my-padding-class{
padding-top: 6rem;
padding-bottom: 6rem;
}
/*Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)*/
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    my-padding-class{
        padding-top: 1rem;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }
}
```

BUT! Do yo want it to be general? for all grid columns? Then you should not define your own class, becasue you dont want to add it over and over again.

Then you should realy look into Sass. I use webpack2 to precompile it

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Check updated question with screen shot.

Comment: Updating the main answer

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the padding class in a breakpoint just like the padding utils do..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .py-md-6 {
      padding-top: 6rem !important;
      padding-bottom: 6rem !important;  
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/MOw2FO7Rmw

Comment: For some reason that didn't work. See screenshot in updated question.

Comment: Basically it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025566/bootstrap-4-spacing-bug/44025627#44025627